# Including header files in ros build system

Tags: ros, build, compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a cpp code with 3 header files for the same written by me. I want to port this code to ros including these header files in my package. I created a package with my .cpp code in src folder and changed the CMakeFile.txt to build the executable of the same. If i have to include these .h files as well to my code where do i place them in the package and how to build my code using the .h files.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31636/including-header-files-in-ros-build-system/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-04-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [usual practice](http://ros.org/wiki/Packages#Common_Files_and_Directories) is to place your headers in `include/package_name`, referencing them like this:

```
#include <package_name/header_name.h>
```

You would fill in your own `package_name` and `header_name`, as appropriate.

They only need to be exported in the `manifest.xml` if other packages include them. Your question implies no need for that.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-04-11**:
Thanks Joq. Ya i was missing the package_name in my include statement. It helped!!

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-04-11**:
+1 for the link to the usual practice; I always wondered if those were written down somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

If I understand you in the right way, everything is very-very simple. You only should to place your .h in /include directory. So, .cpp files will be in yourProject/src, .hpp will be in yourProject/include. And this is all! Ros building system should to find your headers by itself, if they mentioned in your .cpp files.

---

Originally posted by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) with karma: 546 on 2012-04-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-04-11**:
Hey thanks for the response. Are you using in similar way. I did try this and it was not working so i posted this question. Could you check once and reply back.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-04-11**:
Hey it worked!! sorry i missed as small thing. When i created a project, it happened to create /project/include/project folder where i placed my .hpp files. But when i place it back to /project/include it worked.

**Comment by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on 2012-04-11**:
You can use /project/include/project method. As example, I do next: /project/include/module1...N, then in .cpp #include "moduleX/header.h"

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-04-11**:
Hey ya thanks! i got it from Joq's response. :)